# How to make left/right arrow appear only when hovering Magento 2 base image in gallery

Tags: magento2, image, gallery-image

I want to remove left and right arrow when first accessing the product page. By default it was set to appear even when not hovering base image in image gallery. Since it has that overlay effect around the arrows it applies grey overlay which is intrusive.
[image: Arrows]

I'd like those arrows to appear only when hovering base image and not when the page is first loaded. What's weird, if I hover the image and then move cursor away arrows dissapear like they should.